# Ajax call on separate js file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I can use ajax call on *.cshtml file as below.It's working properly.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllBooks", "Book")',
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        self.Books(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
    }
});
```

But How can I call same method on seperate *.js file ?When I used above code it's not working?

Comment: What error is coming ?

Comment: @PKKG No errors.But action method is not firing.

Answer (score 5):

CSHTML (I prefer the tag input):

```
@* without the attribute 'name' *@
<input type="hidden" value="@Url.Action("GetAllBooks", "Book")" id="UrlBookGetAllBooks" />

@* or *@

<div style="display:none;" data-url="@Url.Action("GetAllBooks", "Book")" id="UrlBookGetAllBooks"></div>
```

JS:

```
var url = $('#UrlBookGetAllBooks').val();
//or for tag div
var url = $('#UrlBookGetAllBooks').data('url');

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        self.Books(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**HTML - Contains data- attributes**

```
<div id="ExampleDiv" 
    data-url = "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" })">
</div>
```

**HTML - Option 2**

```
<div id="ExampleDiv" 
    url-Val = "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "AreaName" })">
</div>
```

**JQuery - Contains data- attributes**

```
var Url_Value = $('#ExampleDiv').data('url');
```

**JQuery - Option 2**

```
var Url_Value = $('#ExampleDiv').attr('url-Val');
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: Url_Value,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        self.Books(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
    }
});
```

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: You can also use HTML5's `data-` attributes.

Comment: @Meryovi : Very good point. Thanks. I did that just to consider old browsers. Thanks again for nice point. +1

Answer (score 1):

For such solution, I recommends you to create a JavascriptController with a "JavascriptActionResult" or a new "JavascriptActionResult" on the BookController along with the view that outputs the desired javascript. That way you can write Javascript dynamically with razor and also have garantee that the Route Pattern behavior of your MVC will be followed. With all that set, the page would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("GetAllBooksJS","Book")"></script>
```

PS: There is not a native JavascriptActionResult in MVC, but you could extend the ActionResult to perform that or simple force a Content-Type in the classic ActionResult function.

Bellow is a working case that Ive made in MVC3.

Controller:

```
public class BookController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Book/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAllBooks() {
        return Json(new[] { new { name = "Book1" }, new { name = "Book2" } });

    }
    public ActionResult GetAllBooksJS()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")">        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("GetAllBooksJS","Book")"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button>Get books ajax</button>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

GetAllBooksJS View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function() {
        GetBooksAjax();  
    });
});

function GetBooksAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllBooks","Book")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(oJSON) {
            $.each(oJSON,function(){
                alert(this.name);
            })
        }
    })
}
```

GetAllBooksJS View v2, In this second version the Javascript, as soon as it is loaded by the Index view, will engage the Ajax Call, I guess thats your case:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

function GetBooksAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllBooks","Book")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(oJSON) {
            $.each(oJSON,function(){
                alert(this.name);
            })
        }
    })
}
GetBooksAjax();
```

Comment: Can I have any sample code or useful url for such a implementation ?

Comment: Yeah off course, I will do a case here and edit my post with a sample

Comment: +1 for this approach. I never saw `src` attribute has URL value of any Controller action. waiting for the sample code. Good to know this new approach. Thanks :)

Comment: @Roger : Need to call `GetGoodAjax' from JavaScript File only....and out from Razor View.

Comment: @Roger Yup,@PKKG is right.I need "GetGoodAjax" on *.js file not inside the View ?

Comment: Well, you could achieve that, calling the GetBooksAjax on the document. ready. Once the javascript file loads, it will trigger on documentrady the Ajax, not on the click.

Comment: Keep in your mind that in the GetBooksJS view you can write any javascript that you want as if it was a separated file. Ex: alert('Hello World')..

Comment: JavaScript file is unable to understand `@Url.Action("GetAllBooks","Book")`.

Comment: I really dont see the difference in the js file and the view one, once the resource generated are both text/javascript. By the way I have made a second version that engage some action in the javascript that doesnt depend on the Index view...

Comment: @PKKG, if this approach still not solve your problem, I would suggest to use this solution. Javascript MVC Routing, url: http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/12/20/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing.aspx